# File not found / How to make Python recognize all the files in my folder?

Tags: python

I am an unexperienced programmer and I had to make a chatbot for a project in school, I succeeded in making it but I have a problem with the files I need to import

Using the full file path works, but I can't possible do that since I have to send it to my teacher for review and then present it at school, I have to make it so it recognizes the file in its folder.

I have all the files in one folder, everything is named correctly and I didn't misspell anything (since only pasting the file path before the name I'm trying to import solves my issue). It just keeps saying that it can't find the file, I found multiple questions about this issue, with some work around and some things that solved the issue, but not for me, how do I straight up tell my code " Look here idiot! It's in THE FOLDER THAT YOU ARE IN! "

**CHATBOT ( The one I'm having issues with ):**

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from keras.models import load_model

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intentii = json.loads(open('intentii.json').read())

cuvinte = pickle.load(open('cuvinte.pkl', 'rb'))
clase = pickle.load(open('clase.pkl', 'rb'))
model = load_model('chatbotmodel.h5')

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_cuvinte = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_cuvinte = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(cuvant) for cuvant     in     sentence_cuvinte]
    return sentence_cuvinte

def pachet_de_cuvinte(sentence):
    sentence_cuvinte = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    pachet = [0] * len(cuvinte)
        for w in sentence_cuvinte:
        for i, cuvant in enumerate(cuvinte):
            if cuvant == w:
                pachet[i] = 1
    return np.array(pachet)

def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = pachet_de_cuvinte(sentence)
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
    LIMITA_EROARE = 0.25
    rezultate = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r >     LIMITA_EROARE]

    rezultate.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in rezultate:
        return_list.append({'intentie': clase[r[0]], 'probabilitate': str(r[1])})
    return return_list

def primeste_raspuns(lista_intentii, intentii_json):
    tag = lista_intentii[0]['intentie']
    lista_de_intentii = intentii_json['intentii']
    for i in lista_de_intentii:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['raspunsuri'])
            break
    return result

print("V.A.S.I.L.E a fost initializat!")

while True:
    message = input("")
    ints = predict_class(message)
    res = primeste_raspuns(ints, intentii)
    print(res)
```

**TRAINING (The one where I used the same import for my files and it worked):**

```
from random import random

import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD

lematizare = WordNetLemmatizer()

intentii = json.loads(open('intentii.json').read())

cuvinte = []
clase = []
documente = []
ignora_simboluri = ['?', '!', ',', '.']

for intentie in intentii['intentii']:
    for pattern in intentie['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        cuvinte.extend(word_list)
        documente.append((word_list, intentie['tag']))
        if intentie['tag'] not in clase:
            clase.append(intentie['tag'])
        
cuvinte = [lematizare.lemmatize(cuvant) for cuvant in cuvinte if cuvant not in ignora_simboluri]
cuvinte = sorted(set(cuvinte))

clase = sorted(set(clase))

pickle.dump(cuvinte, open('cuvinte.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(clase, open('clase.pkl', 'wb'))

training = []
output_gol = [0] * len(clase)

for document in documente:
    pachet = []
    cuvant_patterns = document[0]
    cuvant_patterns = [lematizare.lemmatize(cuvant.lower()) for cuvant in cuvant_patterns]
    for cuvant in cuvinte:
        pachet.append(1) if cuvant in cuvant_patterns else     pachet.append(0)
    
    output_row = list(output_gol)
    output_row[clase.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([pachet, output_row])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

tmodel = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbotmodel.h5', tmodel)
print("Gata!")
```

Comment: Posting your code would be helpful

Comment: You can use `os.getcwd()` to see the current path (and use it when calling your files). But it's difficult to debug anything without any code.

Comment: BTW, Python is not supposed to be clever, it just does whatever you tell it to do. And because this is a public forum, you may want to eliminate unnecessary expletives.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly and RJ Adriaansen
Sorry for not posting the code! I updated my post! Also, I have 2 files, 1 is for training the bot and the other one is for the chatbot itself, in the training file, importing the .json file is working with my current code, but on the chatbot one, its not, I will post both codes

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly what your problem is, but I feel like you are asking for this`./filename`, but if you are using windows then it's `.\` `(.\filename)`

Comment: my GOD man, when I saw this comment I was like "OH MY GOD THIS IS IT LOOK THIS WILL WORK FOR SURE 10000%", tried ./ and it didnt, but remembered the file path is with \ not / and tried it, guess what, IT DID WORK, basically tells python "yeah search everywhere\filename", you are the best man, have a good one

Comment: Oh, :Dd Nice work. My bad I didn't switched to widnows in my mind. Glad you could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

to get the relative filepaths, use `__file__`

```py
from pathlib import Path

this_file = Path(__file__).absolute()
this_file_directory = this_file.parent
```

so if your structure is:

```
top_dir
├── code_dir
|    └── main.py
└── data
    └── something.json
```

in `main.py`

```py
from pathlib import Path

top_dir = Path(__file__).absolute().parent.parent
data_dir = top_dir / 'data'
data_file = data_dir / 'something.json'
```

and this will work for anyone